# Function chaining is also considered as callbacks?

Tags: c#

When I implement a chaining such as in:

ToUpper().ToString(). ....

Would that chaining also be considered as a callback ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually a callback is in the form of delegate that is passed as an argument to another object or method call. It allows a lower-level object to call a method defined in a higher level object.

```
public void Caller()
{
    // We can use an anonymous method for our call back...
    this.PerformAction(() => Console.WriteLine("Callback invoked"));
}

public void PerformAction(Action callback)
{
    // perform a task and invoke the call back
    callback.Invoke();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, it would not be.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.myelin.co.nz/notes/callbacks/cs-delegates.html) is a very quick overview of what a call back is and what you use it for.

Answer (score 1):

No it wouldn't, to use a simple example.

This:

```
string foo = bar.ToString().ToUpper();
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
string foo = bar.ToString();
foo = foo.ToUpper();
```